# Imoving magento website

Tags: magento

I have a 2 GB of magento site, which I want to move from one server to another. Is there a way to be specific with folders like app folder or skin folder and move them only to new magento directory? As I did that the magento setup came up, but I have a database already. Is there anyway I can just move the main folders and database to new server?

Comment: The question is fine, he's obviously wanting to migrate to another server withing moving the whole filebase..

Comment: Not a programming question. Magento help-desk questions belong over in Magento.Stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup screen will appear if your local setup file hasn't been copied over

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

Copy this over and update it with your new servers Database credentials and it should connect rather than asking you to setup the new store.

You should then be able to transfer your theme's design and skin folders over to the new store without any issue.

```
app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/
skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/
```

You substitute in the values of your package / theme names above.

Comment: and make sure your domain name is same else you need to change it manually in the database too in core_config_data table.